# AspNetBoilerplate : server side enum usage on front end (angular)?

Tags: angular, enums, .net-core, aspnetboilerplate

We are trying to use `AspNetBoilerplate` framework (`.NET Core` version with `angular`, free version template).

I would like to create `Enums` on backend and also use them on `angular` side (so we need to generate them from server side code). **Can you, please, give me some clues how better to achieve this with given framework?**

Maybe there is already something built in to:

1. To generate server side Enums on client side
2. Having some specific methods on Enum on client side like finding Enum-id by name or vice versa
3. Are there something built in on server side for Enums (some specific attributes or anything else).
4. The very same question can exist for Constants also

Comment: You should only have one source of truth. This means that you should request your enums with an HTTP request, and do not duplicate them. If you duplicate them, everytime you change them, you will have to make the same changes to every other duplicate.

Comment: @trichetriche One source of truth would be on sever side, code would be genereted on client side and nobody would chang it, as it would be generated....

Comment: Nope. There was an incomplete attempt: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/pull/378

Comment: If it's generated, it's generated at some point in time for some data. If you generate it everytime a user opens the Application (which I don't think is possible), then that's the equivalent of makign HTTP calls.

Comment: @trichetriche it is a common practice to generate enums, of course, not every time. AspNetBoilerplate already generates classes and service proxies, so it is simply programmers responsibility to run generation toool, otherwise it is not working. If you do not have enums on front end defined (generated), you cannot use like (CustomerType == Customer.B2B) etc.

Comment: @renathy that's true, I didn't get your question like that, I apologize ! I know that in Java, you have maven plugins that can do that. Don't you have a package manager in ASP.NET that could offer some packages that would do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I used Reinforced.Typings ([wiki](https://github.com/reinforced/Reinforced.Typings/wiki)) to generate clientside classes from serverside. They do enums as well: just decorate your serverside enum definition with [Ts_Enum] tag and on each compile it will regenerate your enums on the clientside.